Error using Proton to deploy Shiny app as a standalone application
I am trying to deploy a Shiny app as a standalone application for deployment on computers that have no internet access.
The following issues occur using the instructions  via Columbus Collabatory
remotes::install_github("ColumbusCollaboratory/photon")
library(photon)
photon:::photon_rstudioaddin()

Results in the following error

Error in if (getAttribs(panels[[i]])$value %in% open) { :
the condition has length > 1

Any assistance solving this issue i greatly appreciated. As is any other advice that might assist the primary task noted above. Thx
